# Token not being generated when using a 509 certificate for authentication

Tags: api, authentication, ms-office, console-application, office365

I am getting an authentication error when trying to launch a console app which is trying to contact Microsoft outlook api.  I created this application with console log which I will display the in this question.  Seems like I am getting this error when trying to acquire the token silently, but from every example I seen, seems like I am doing it correctly.
these are the two functions which I see are causing the error.

Token Acquiring function for authentication :

```
   private static string EMAIL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "********@dell.com";
    private static string EMAIL_SERVICE_PWD = "*******";        
    private static string ClientID = "************************";
    private static string ClientSecret ="**********************";
    private static Uri ReturnUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44300/");
    private static string CommonAuthority = "https://login.windows.net/Common";
    public static AuthenticationContext AuthContext { get; set; }
    private static async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(string authContextUrl, string resourceId)
    {
        AuthenticationResult ar = null;
        try
        {              
            AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextUrl);               

            if (AuthContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            { 
                string cachedAuthority =
                    AuthContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority;
                AuthContext = new AuthenticationContext(cachedAuthority);
            }

            //ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientID, ClientSecret); << not invoking this 
            ar = (await AuthContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceId, ClientID));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //not in cache; we'll get it with the full oauth flow
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException);
        }

        if (ar == null)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(EMAIL_SERVICE_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_SERVICE_PWD);
                ar = AuthContext .AcquireToken(resourceId, ClientID, uc);
            }
            catch (Exception acquireEx)
            {
                //utter failure here, we need let the user know we just can't do it
                Console.WriteLine("Error trying to acquire authentication result: " + acquireEx.Message);
                if (acquireEx.InnerException != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", acquireEx.InnerException);
            }
        }
        return ar;
    }
```

This is my function creating the OutLook client

```
         private static async Task<OutlookServicesClient> GetOutlookClient()
    {
        OutlookServicesClient oc = null;

        try
        { 
            string MAIL_RESOURCE_ID = "https://outlook.office365.com";

            AuthenticationResult ar = await AcquireTokenAsync(CommonAuthority, MAIL_RESOURCE_ID);

            if (ar != null)
            {
                oc = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0"), () =>
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    return ar.AccessToken;
                }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting Outlook client: " + ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", ex.InnerException);
        }

        return oc;
    }
```

This is the error that I am getting

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @ Daniel had to restart PC the error has now been posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a work around for what I want to do, I decided to go ahead with a x509 cert v2 in order to go around this issue, I also found that this was going to work much better for my project because it was going to be a console app.  Here goes a snippet of my code to efficiently get a token in order to authenticate against Azure. 
509 Cert to get token for auth:

```
    public static string Aquire_Token()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        try
        {
            string authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"];

            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

            string certfile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientCertificatePfx"];

            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certfile, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientCertificatePfxPassword"], X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

            ClientAssertionCertificate cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(CLIENTID, cert);

            authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(RESOURCEID, cac);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Issue with Aquireing Token :" + ex.Message);
        }
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
}
```